# change CSS to work with jQuery toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Weave:** http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#e3d0eadc38078efe27c7785d6e4a6e1a

[image]

I'm having a floating action button (material design style) on my site. Currently it is triggered by the :hover property and plain CSS. I want to change it to open on click and was planning to use the toggle function of jQuery.

I'm trying to replicate the menu from [mydivision.net](http://mydivision.net/) (bottom right corner)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("span#fab").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.fab {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 32px;
  right: 32px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.fab-button {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  text-align: center;
}

.fab-button:active,
.fab-button:focus,
.fab-button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.56);
}

.fab-button:not(:last-child) {
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(50px) scale(0.2);
  transform: translateY(50px) scale(0.2);
}

.fab:hover .fab-button:not(:last-child) {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  margin: 15px auto 0;
}

.fab-button i {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 21px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 42px;
}

.fab-button:nth-last-child(1) i {
  line-height: 56px;
}

.fab-button:nth-last-child(1) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 25ms;
  transition-delay: 25ms;
  background-color: #ff6d10;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fab-button:not(:last-child):nth-last-child(2) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 50ms;
  transition-delay: 50ms;
  background-color: #78c831;
}

.fab-button:not(:last-child):nth-last-child(3) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 75ms;
  transition-delay: 75ms;
  background-color: #3f73fc;
}

.fab-button:not(:last-child):nth-last-child(4) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 100ms;
  transition-delay: 100ms;
  background-color: #6d5593;
}

.fab-button:not(:last-child):nth-last-child(5) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 125ms;
  transition-delay: 125ms;
  background-color: #f8ba24;
}

.fab-button:not(:last-child):nth-last-child(6) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 150ms;
  transition-delay: 150ms;
  background-color: #1fc36a;
}

.fab-button:not(:last-child):nth-last-child(7) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 175ms;
  transition-delay: 175ms;
  background-color: #242424;
}

.fab .fab-button:nth-last-child(1) i {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.fab:hover .fab-button:nth-last-child(1) i {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

[tooltip]:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 22%;
  right: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #242424;
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(tooltip);
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

[tooltip]:hover:before,
[tooltip]:hover:after {
  background-color: #000;
}

.fab:hover [tooltip]:before,
.fab:hover [tooltip]:after {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/4.1.1/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="fab">
  <a class="fab-button" href="#" tooltip="blaah"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-up"></i></a>
  <a class="fab-button" href="#" tooltip="blaah"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
  <a class="fab-button" href="#" tooltip="blaah"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></a>
  <a class="fab-button" href="#" tooltip="blaah"><i class="fa fa-microphone"></i></a>
  <a class="fab-button" href="#" tooltip="blaah"><i class="fa fa-gavel"></i></a>
  <a class="fab-button" href="#" tooltip="Forum"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i></a>
  <span class="fab-button" id="fab"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span>
</nav>
```

**I thought I could use the following jQuery script:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("span#fab").click(function () {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

Now the question is: How do I have to amend the existing CSS so that the new class "active" is opening the menu on click?

Thanks!

Comment: From the sounds of it, you just need to go through your CSS replacing `:hover` with `.active`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Weave:** http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#e884e37313af26b5738f11b2446bfb20

The menu opens from [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover). If you use the [:active](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) pseudo selector you will have to hold your mouse down for the menu to be open (In short [:active](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) is basically a [mousedown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousedown)/[touchstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchstart) event in CSS)

You don't actually need JQuery for this effect! You could open/close the menu using a [checkbox](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#f20247005d0fae22632b0b8dac08ae4e) or the [:target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) [pseudo selector](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#31bea6fcf1c7f03828438ee6835ba61d).

I chose to use a checkbox in my snippet below.

I removed some of the vendor prefixes in your CSS and replaced it with [Prefix-Free](https://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree) to keep your code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

```css
.fab {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 32px;
  right: 32px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.fab-button {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu:checked,
.fab-button:active,
.fab-button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.56);
}

.fab-button:not(:last-child) {
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(50px) scale(0.2);
}

#menu:checked ~ .fab-button:not(:last-child) {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: none;
  margin: 15px auto 0;
}

.fab-button i {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 21px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 42px;
}

.fab-button:nth-last-child(1) i {
  line-height: 56px;
}

.fab-button:nth-last-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 25ms;
  background: #ff6d10;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fab-button:not(:last-child):nth-last-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 50ms;
  background: #78c831;
}

.fab-button:not(:last-child):nth-last-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 75ms;
  background: #3f73fc;
}

.fab-button:not(:last-child):nth-last-child(4) {
  transition-delay: 100ms;
  background: #6d5593;
}

.fab-button:not(:last-child):nth-last-child(5) {
  transition-delay: 125ms;
  background: #f8ba24;
}

.fab-button:not(:last-child):nth-last-child(6) {
  transition-delay: 150ms;
  background: #1fc36a;
}

.fab-button:not(:last-child):nth-last-child(7) {
  transition-delay: 175ms;
  background: #242424;
}

.fab .fab-button:nth-last-child(1) i {
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

#menu:checked ~ .fab-button:nth-last-child(1) i {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

[tooltip]:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 22%;
  right: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #242424;
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(tooltip);
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

[tooltip]:hover:before,
[tooltip]:hover:after {
  background: #000;
}

#menu:checked ~ [tooltip]:before,
#menu:checked ~ [tooltip]:after {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/4.1.1/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/prefixfree.js"></script>

<nav class="fab">
  <input type="checkbox" id="menu">

  <a class="fab-button" href="#" tooltip="blaah"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-up"></i></a>
  <a class="fab-button" href="#" tooltip="blaah"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
  <a class="fab-button" href="#" tooltip="blaah"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></a>
  <a class="fab-button" href="#" tooltip="blaah"><i class="fa fa-microphone"></i></a>
  <a class="fab-button" href="#" tooltip="blaah"><i class="fa fa-gavel"></i></a>
  <a class="fab-button" href="#" tooltip="Forum"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i></a>
  <label for="menu" class="fab-button" id="fab"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></label>
</nav>
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much. Even better without JS. I did only one more thing: Hiding the checkbox via "display: none".

Comment: Remember this type of [toggle method can be used a variety of ways](http://codepen.io/mikethedj4/pen/ZWjyLO) and is [supported on all major browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label). Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

This line is where the party's at `.fab:hover .fab-button:not(:last-child) {opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: none; transform: none; margin: 15px auto 0;}`

So you need to change `fab:hover` to `fab.active` on this line and wherever else it occurs.

Comment: Thanks James. That's what I tried as a first thing but it does not work.